# Magento CE 1.9.0.0 downloadable product does not open uploader

Tags: product, downloadable, ce-1.9.0.0

In Magento CE 1.9.0.0 I have the problem that when I add a downloadable product in backend and want to add the file by clicking  "Add new row" nothing happens.

The console reports:

SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
'Dieser Inhalt erfordert die neueste Version des Adobe Flash

Does someone know in which file the error occurs?

Comment: What browser are you using? Are you using ssl or self signed certificate? Also see http://helpx.adobe.com/de/flash-player/kb/flash-player-issues-windows-8.html

Comment: I havet tested it in Firefox, Chrome and IE without SSL or certificates. It seems that there is somewhere a linebreak that produces this error because this line 'Dieser Inhalt erfordert die neueste Version des Adobe Flash Players. <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash/">Flash herunterladen</a> has no '+ at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for the answer I came across a hint that was the solution. The Problem is probably caused by a language file:

Answer (score 2):

The file uploader uses flash, please make sure you have an up to date version of flash installed for your browser.

Comment: Yes, if I test the same procedure in CE 1.9.0.1 everything works fine

Comment: Does this happen on a clean install without any extensions or customisations?

Comment: Yes, it is a clean install

Answer (score 0):

The root cause for this problem is the file `app/locale/de_DE/Mage_Media.csv` which somehow contains an additional line break at the end of the file:

```
"This content requires last version of Adobe Flash Player. Get Flash","Dieser Inhalt erfordert die neueste Version des Adobe Flash Players. Flash herunterladen 
"
```

Of course this can easily be fixed by removing additional line break or adding a translate.csv to your admin theme and adding the line

```
"Mage_Media::This content requires last version of Adobe Flash Player. Get Flash","Dieser Inhalt erfordert die neueste Version des Adobe Flash Players. Flash herunterladen"
```

Comment: @ ramesh : Did you know about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429277/error-in-fedex-shipping-method-in-magento  this error solution

Comment: @JeevaRathinam : Yes, I know. May be you are missing weight. You may trace feedex response and url here in `/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php`
Note :- Please don't do any permanent changes in base file

Comment: @ Ramesh Kumar : join http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56921/discussion-between-ajay-patel-and-rathinam, i am post all the details